# How to make an login form, my button doesnt do anything

Tags: c#, winforms

First at all i am new at visual C#. I am trying to make a simple login form with only password login, but when i press button nothing happens. I want to check if there is a user in db which is online.

I dont know where i am making the mistake.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace SportStat.Forme
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btnUlaz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ulaz();
        }
        private void ulaz()
        {
            if (txtPassword.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Morate upisati lozinku", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);             
                return;
            }
            var sql = "select * from users where password='" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
            var dt = sustav.puniDt(sql);
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Neispravna lozinka", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                txtPassword.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if ((string)dt.Rows[0]["password"] != txtPassword.Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Neispravna lozinka", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                txtPassword.Focus();
                return;
            }
            sustav i = new sustav();
            i.idUser = (int)dt.Rows[0]["idUser"];
            i.pswd = (int)dt.Rows[0]["pswd"];
            i.prezimeIme = (int)dt.Rows[0]["prezimeIme"];
            i.idKlub = (int)dt.Rows[0]["idKlub"];
            int count = i.pswd;
            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successful!");
                this.Hide(); 

                frmMain fm = new frmMain();
                fm.Show();
            } 
            this.Close();
        }
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with this problem.

Comment: where does it give up? trace through the code and follow what it does, this should reveal why its not doing what you expect

Comment: Without explaining the actual error, it's going to be very hard for us to help you. We can't search through your code.

Look up breakpoints, they'll help you see whether or not the code is even getting to the 'ulaz()' function. If it is, then you know there is an issue inside that function. If not, then it's likely there is an issue with with the linking of the code to the button.

Comment: `var sql = "select * from users where password='" + txtPassword.Text + "'";` probably not your problem but _please_ do not do this! Use SQL Params. Also: I guess this is far from productive code but just for the protocol: _do not store plain text passwords_.

Comment: when i try to submit an empty textbox it doesn't do anything, and it should display me an error msg

Comment: Try to *Rebuild* your project once and try again.

Comment: Instead of `if (txtPassword.Text == "")` try :`if ( string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtPassword.Text))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't comment, too low rep..

Try to put another button on the form and call ulaz(); from that new button.

Sometimes, if you delete button and add them again, or copy paste code, methods get autoassign another name.

For example:

```
 private void btnUlaz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ulaz();
    }

private void btnUlaz_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ulaz();
    }
```

First one wont work.
I don't know if this is the case in your problem but it's worth trying..